# how cmake can check which Visual C++ version runs behind NMAKE

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017, nmake

I am working on a CMake project for Windows which uses 'NMake' as generator.

Inside my CMake I have to setup variables differently based on the specific version of Visual C++ which will compile the code.  Specifically I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2013.

How can I distinguish withing the CMakeLists.txt when NMake is generating its files for Visual Studio 2017 instead of Visual Studio 2013?

Is there any CMake variable I can read to know which version of Visual C++ will be used?

Is there maybe a NMake version under CMAke?

Unfortunately I have to stick to 'NMake' generator and I cannot switch to the two generators which would solve easily my problem which are 'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64' and 'Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64'.

Comment: Intention not clear. The generated NMake Makefiles will use the MSVC version that belongs to the NMake version you are executing, i.e. the MSVC version depends on which MSVC version is active (PATH, environment variables etc.). Do you want to base decisions of your CMake script on the MSVC version used, or do you ask how to switch between MSVC versions?

Comment: To elaborate, I work on a machine with multiple MSVC versions installed. I "activate" the version I want (in a "vanilla" DOS box) by e.g. `call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd 64`. (This activating MSVC 10 in the 64bit config.) I then generate the NMake files, call NMake, and get my MSVC 10 build. I can then open a different DOS box, do the same "activation call" for e.g. `VS80COMNTOOLS`, create a different set of NMake files, and create a MSVC 8 build with the NMake that comes with *that* version of MSVC. Does any of this help?

Comment: Thanks for your info anyway. True, my question was not clean so I rewrote it. I've found variable MSVC_VERSION . I'll give it a try and let you know. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/MSVC_VERSION.html

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile What was the outcome? Did the NMake generator fill MSVC_VERSION? Or did you find another solution?