# CMake NMake generator not generating ${PlatformToolset} variable

Tags: cmake, nmake

I have a find_package script that uses `${PlatformToolset}` and `${Platform}` to find the correct directories. However, when using the nmake generator, it seems these are not set. Am I correct in thinking that these variables are not set, or am I doing something wrong? Is there a replacement for these variables?

Comment: related but without answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47145999/how-cmake-can-check-which-visual-c-version-runs-behind-nmake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NMake sets MSVC_VERSION and other MSVC variables, so Platformtoolset and Platform can be derived from that:

```
if(MSVC_VERSION GREATER 1900)
    set(PlatformToolSet v141)
else()
    set(PlatformToolSet v140)
endif()

if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P GREATER 4)
  set(Platform x64)
else()
  set(Platform Win32)
endif()
```